# How to check if "media_send_to_editor" is audio?

Tags: filters, uploads, visual-editor

I'm using a function to create additional fields on media upload. They are important only for images and videos, but useless and even confusing to my users if they are uploading audio.

This is the function:

```
function give_linked_images_data($html, $id, $caption, $title, $align, $url, $size, $alt = '' ){
    $classes = 'img image-link';
    if (get_post_meta($id, "pop_title") == '') $poptitle = ''; else $poptitle = ' data-title="'. get_post_meta($id, "pop_title", true) .'"';    
    $html = preg_replace('/(<a.*?)>/', '$1 data-toggle="lightbox" '. $poptitle .' ' . $classes . '" >', $html);
    return $html;
}
```

The functions is added with

```
add_filter('image_send_to_editor','give_linked_images_data',10,8);
```

...and I have a similar function using

```
add_filter('media_send_to_editor','give_linked_images_data',10,8);
```

...but it runs on video **and** audio upload. How can I detect if the media being uploaded is audio, to disable the custom fields?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can simplify the *mime type* checks, with the following *boolean* functions:

- `wp_attachment_is( 'image', $id )`
- `wp_attachment_is( 'video', $id )`
- `wp_attachment_is( 'audio', $id )`

where `$id` is the attachment ID.

The attachment's ID is actually one of the input arguments for the `media_send_to_editor` filter callback.

We also have:

- `wp_attachment_is_image( $id )`

that's a wrapper for `wp_attachment_is( 'image', $id )`.

**References:**

- [`wp_attachment_is()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_attachment_is/)
- [`wp_attachment_is_image()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_attachment_is_image/)
- [`media_send_to_editor`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/media_send_to_editor/)

Comment: My answer works but this is way better, thank you.

Comment: Glad to hear it worked for you. @DanielLemes

Answer (score 1):

I found out how:

```
$mime_type = get_post_mime_type($post->ID);
// all mime https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_allowed_mime_types

// videos and images only
$permit_mime = array('image/jpeg','image/gif','image/png','image/bmp','image/tiff','image/x-icon','video/x-ms-asf','video/x-ms-wmv','video/x-ms-wmx','video/x-ms-wm','video/avi','video/divx','video/x-flv','video/quicktime','video/mpeg','video/mp4','video/ogg','video/webm','video/x-matroska');
// if is video or image
if (in_array($mime_type, $permit_mime)) {
    // the function
}
```